# How could I make myheritage print tree with step-dads?

Tags: myheritage.com

There is nice tree printing mode for posters in myheritage.com.
I use "ancestors" mode to print all ancestors for my daughter. 
But it prefers "birth" dads to step-dads, but in our familiy tree printing there is places where we actually prefer step-dads (cause of birth "dads" not being really part of family).

The same problem goes in match algorithms. I'm not interested in every marriage relatives match, but I interested in my step grand-grand father ansectors.

How I could mark step dads as "prefferable"?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Speaking not as a mod here, but as a member of the community who is also an adopted kid, may I ask you to reconsider the terminology you've used in your question? The term "real parent" is problematic.  See https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3350/1006

Comment: @JanMurphy Revised. More suggestions welcome

Answer (score 2):

I would create a new tree for each step-relative you want to trace. Your step-relative should be the central person and it should include all his/her relatives. You could include his/her step children in the tree as if they were real. I'd then remove him/her from my main tree so I won't have to maintain information in both trees. Then whenever hints come in from your step-tree, you'll know they're for your step family.